# Why a function need a class which contain itself as parameter rather than a string which defined?

Tags: ios, swift4

My class is look like this :

```
class MyNewClass {
   func myNewFunction (paramString : String) -> String {
      var myString = ""

      if paramString.caseInsensitiveCompare("A") == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {
            myString = "The string is A"
        }else{
            myString = "The string is blank"
      }
      return myString
   }
}
```

This have no problem.But when I use this class in another `ViewContoller` ,it give me a weird error.

I call the `myNewFunction` like this in another `ViewController`

```
let myString : String = MyNewClass.myNewFunction("A")
```

Suppose I should insert "A" into `myNewFunction()` as a `paramString` which I define in `MyNewClass`,but I get a warning like this

> 'String' is not convertible to 'MyNewClass'

I just dont know why I cant parse a `String` as the parameter of `myNewFunction()`.And why the `myNewFunction()` need the class contain it which is `MyNewClass` as its parameter?

Someone please guide me to the right direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call it without initiating an instance of `MyNewClass`, you can prepend `static` before `func`, like

```
class MyNewClass {
  static func myNewFunction (paramString : String) -> String {
      var myString = ""

      if paramString.caseInsensitiveCompare("A") == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {
            myString = "The string is A"
      } else {
            myString = "The string is blank"
      }

      return myString
   }
}
```

`MyNewClass.myNewFunction(paramString: "foo")`

Optinally, you can create an instance of MyNewClass.

```
let myInstance = MyNewClass()
let myString = myInstance.myNewFunction(paramString: "foo")
```

Comment: so if I use `static` my `MyNewClass` what is `static` means?

Comment: The `static` keyword is the same as `class func/var` in some languages, if you have experience with that. It just means the function isn't a member of the instance, so for example, you can't use `self` in a static function because `self` isn't there. Think of the static function/property as a global function namespaced by your classes name. I'm not a CS grad so I can't really explain it properly, sorry!